# Let $W = \textit{span}\{\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2,\mathbf{w}_3\}$...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = \text{span}\{\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2,\mathbf{w}_3\}$, where \begin{equation*}
\mathbf{w}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{w}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{w}_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
2 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
1. Find a basis $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n\}$ for $W$.
Let
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
be a matrix that contains the vectors in $W$. Row reducing $A$ leads to $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. We see that the first two columns are pivots (meaning they are linearly independent) so the basis for $W$ is
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
2. Find a basis $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_m\}$ for $W^{\perp}$.
So do we transpose $A$ then reduce and then find a basis for the null space?
3. Write each $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ uniquely in the form
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x} = a_1\mathbf{v}_1+\ldots+a_n\mathbf{v}_n+b_1\mathbf{u}_1+\ldots +b_m\mathbf{u}_m.
\end{equation*}
Here the coeffieients $a_j$ and $b_k$ will depend on $\mathbf{x}$.
Not sure how to do that one. Please help!

Comment: For #2 you may use your work from #1. Since the last row in your row reduced form is all $0$s, a basis for the nullspace of transpose $A$ is the last row of $E$ in $EA = R$. Alternatively you could just eyeball as the first and last rows of $A$ are same.

Comment: Great my basis is $(-1,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $2)$, you could take the cross product of $(1,2,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$.

Get $\begin {vmatrix} i&j&k\\1&2&1\\1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=(2,0,-2)$.

For $3)$, given $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, we need to solve $\begin {pmatrix}1&1&2\\2&0&0\\1&1&-2\end{pmatrix}\vec y=\vec x$.

Thus, $\vec y=\begin {pmatrix}1&1&2\\2&0&0\\1&1&-2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\vec x$, where $\vec y=(a_1,a_2,b_1)$.

Comment: Great thank you I got $(-1,0,1)$ for my basis (which is just a scalar multiple of yours). I have a question what is $\vec{x}$?

Comment: Oh right never mind we don't know! We just find $\vec{y}$ and then substitute that into $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Right.  $\vec x$  is the vector we are given.

Comment: Okay I got $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}x_2$, $a_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1-x_2+x_3)$ and $b_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_3-x_1)$. Then we just throw those into $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Yes.  Plug the coordinates of $\vec x$ in.

Comment: Right so we get $\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{2}x_2\mathbf{v}_1 + \frac{1}{2}(x_1-x_2+x_3)\mathbf{v}_2+\frac{1}{2}(x_3-x_1)\mathbf{v}_3$ thanks a lot.

Comment: Good.  You inverted the matrix I take it.

Comment: Yup it is $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ hence the $\frac{1}{2}$ in each of the $a_1,a_2$ and $b_1$.

Comment: Excellent!   Nice job.

Comment: That will be given to you.  Remember it says the answer "depends on $\vec x$".  $x_1$ will be $\vec x$'s first coordinate.   Like say $\vec x=(1,2,3)$.  Then $x_1=1,x_2=2$ and $x_3=3$.

Comment: Yup got it thanks!